# Moving sharepoint to a new subdomain

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

Is it possible to move an existing Sharepoint farm to a different url on existing infrastructure? Something like host.com to subdomain.host.com?

I work for a public school system in the U.S and we are in the process of moving away from Sharepoint. We previously used Sharepoint for EVERYTHING and need to keep an archive of all the legacy content we have.

Everything I've read so far is that we'll need to spin up new servers and migrate the content. This is also a public school system so budgeting for new infrastructure is going to be an uphill battle...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the steps would be the following:

- Add or change the Alternate Access Mapping
- Edit the IIS binding for the IIS Site hosting the Web Application
- Update DNS
- Update the Search content source with the new Web Application URL and perform a full crawl

If you want to move the SharePoint *Servers* to a new Active Directory domain, yes you need to create a new farm and transfer Service Apps/Content Databases to the new farm.